# Web Essentials .Less compiler 'Out of stack space'

Tags: visual-studio-2012, less

Hi I am getting this error with the [Web Essentials 2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6) extension for Visual Studio:

```
/*
ERROR: ERROR:
  type: Syntax
  message: Out of stack space
  filename: C:\Users\username\myproject\style.less
  column: -1
  extract: ,,@media screen and (max-width:1124px) 

*/
```

The offending line in the less file is this:

```
@media screen and (max-width:1124px) 
{
}
```

So Web Essentials doesn't like media queries or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is coming from the LESS compiler itself and not directly from Web Essentials. The compiler is version 1.3.1, but you might have the older version of the compiler depending on your version of Web Essentials. Get the latest nightly build here: http://madskristensen.net/custom/webessentials2012.vsix?1.8.9.1